# How do I read from QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I have this simple C++ program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess ps;
    QByteArray ba;

    ps.start("ls J:");
    ba = ps.readAllStandardOutput();
    char *someData = ba.data();

    cout << "Testing QProcess ..." << endl;
    cout << someData << endl;
    cout << "done!" << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output is:

```
Testing QProcess ...


done!
```

If I run "ls J:" from Windows cmd it works.
What am I missing?

Comment: hmmm... M$ implements linux's `ls` ?

Comment: @borisbn: because I have MSYS in my system that wy ls works. Even if I change to something Windows e.g. "dir J:" it does not work on my program but it works on Windows cmd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [QIODevice::waitForReadyRead()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead) in a loop, and only after that returns, then call `readAllStandardOutput()`. As it says in the docs, [`QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) will read all *available* data, but will not wait. And before you start reading, you need to wait that process is started with [`QProcess::waitForStarted()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#waitForStarted).

Quick untested partial code, replace line `ba = ps.readAllStandardOutput();` with this:

```
if (ps.waitForStarted(-1)) {
    while(ps.waitForReadyRead(-1)) {
        ba += ps.readAllStandardOutput();
    }
}
// else report error or whatever
```

That should exit the loop when there is error or child process terminates, but keep reading until then, with no timeout.

Note: in a "regular" Qt program, you would have event loop running, and then you would not call `waitForReadyRead()` or other similar convenience functions. They would block the event loop and stop everything else too. In such a program, you would *preferably* use signals and slots, or alternatively start mucking about with threads (but that's generally not preferred, it just adds unnecessary complexity).

Comment: using QIODevice::waitForReadyRead() in a loop, do you mean event loop or while/if-else loops?

Comment: tested the piece of code you added, it gave the same output as before.

Comment: @Amani Are you sure this `ls` prints to standard output and not standard error? Try using `setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels)`.

Comment: Also, *inside* the loop, try adding `qDebug() << ps.bytesAvailable();`  before you call the read method.

Comment: Now it works with the added code, but if I change "ls J:" to "dir J:" it give me same output as before.

Comment: @Amani That's possibly because `dir` is internal command of `cmd.exe`, so you would have to execute `cmd.exe /c dir`.

Answer (score 3):

[`QProcess` documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html) says, that `QProcess` object emits signals when there is data available to read: `readyRead()` and `readyReadStandardOutput()` and `readyReadStandardError()`.

Easiest way is to connect those signals to your slots, and make your reading with eg. `readAllStandardOutput()` there.

Of course hydes loop works also.